# Issues converting string to array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm writing a function that takes in an integer string and converts it to an array. Then, at each element in the array, change the value, convert the array back into a string, and return the string. This code gives an error. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public static void swap(int[] encrypted, int i, int j)
{
 int temp = encrypted[i]; encrypted[i] = encrypted[j]; encrypted[j] =  
 temp;
}

// Input string should only be 4 digits. Ex "1234"
public static String encrypt(String str)
{
 int i;
 int len = str.length(); // get length of string
 int[] encrypted = new int[len]; // size of array

 for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
 {
  // this should be placing integer at string position
  // i, altering its value, and then placing it in 
  // encrypted[i]. This does not work
  encrypted[i] = str.toIntArray(i) + 7 % 10;
 }
 // swaps elements in array
 swap(encrypted, 0, 2);
 swap(encrypted, 1, 3);
 // should convert the array back into a string.
 // Also might not work
 str = String.valueOf(encrypted);
 
// return new string
 return str;
}
```

Given input string "1234", I expect the output to be 0189.
1 + 7 % 10 = 8... and so on.
Swap index 0 and 2, 1 and 3.
I am still not used to all the Java commands, as I am still learning. If there is something I am not doing right, please let me know.

Comment: There is no `toIntArray` method on `String`. Where is your `swap` method defined? Finally, what actual problem do you have? Please post code which compiles, and ask a specific question about its behaviour, or if you can't get it to compile, post the compiler error message. See [ask].

Comment: Is there a comparable toCharArray for int arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** `String` does not have any method with a name, `toIntArray`.

Replace

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
 {
  // this should be placing integer at string position
  // i, altering its value, and then placing it in 
  // encrypted[i]. This does not work
  encrypted[i] = str.toIntArray(i) + 7 % 10;
 }
```

with

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    encrypted[i] = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i)) + 7 % 10;
}
```

**2.** Check the indices before using them e.g. before using `swap(encrypted, 0, 3)`, you should check if `encrypted.length > 3`.

**3.** Correct the way you are converting the array back to a string.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(encrypt("12345678"));
    }

    public static String encrypt(String str) {
        int i;
        int len = str.length();
        int[] encrypted = new int[len];

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            encrypted[i] = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i)) + 7 % 10;
        }

        if (encrypted.length > 3) {
            swap(encrypted, 0, 3);
        }
        if (encrypted.length > 4) {
            swap(encrypted, 1, 4);
        }

        // Convert the array back into a string.
        str = Arrays.stream(encrypted).boxed().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining());

        // Return new string
        return str;
    }

    static void swap(int[] arr, int x, int y) {
        int temp = arr[x];
        arr[x] = arr[y];
        arr[y] = temp;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
11121089131415
```

Comment: I just caught the swap error. The length is always four so it should be swap(0,2) and swap(1,3). I tried your edit with the input string being 1234. The output I got is [I@4a574795.   Im expecting the output to be 0189. 1 +7 %10 = 8.... and so on. Then swap array at position 0 and 2, and 1 and 3. I edited my code to be compilable. If you can help, that would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @idkusrname126 - Are you sure you have tried my updated answer? I've already tested it and also posted a sample test. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Just saw your updated answer. Converting the array back to a string gave me an error "     str = Arrays.stream(encrypted).boxed().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining());
                                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable Collectors
  location: class problem
1 error

Comment: What is the version of Java you are using? You can get it using the command, `java -version` on the terminal window or command prompt.

Comment: Im on version 13.0.2

Comment: Then you must be doing some typo. SImply copy and paste my whole program. Check [this out in an online editor](https://ideone.com/1svL4E).

Comment: It works now, Thank you!

Comment: You are most welcome. Wish you success!

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
encrypted[i] = str.toIntArray(i) + 7 % 10;
```

try

```
encrypted[i] = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(str.charAt(i)))+ 7 % 10;
```

Comment: I tried your answer with the input string being 1234. The output I got is [I@4a574795. Im expecting the output to be 0189. 1 +7 %10 = 8.... and so on. Then swap array at position 0 and 2, and 1 and 3. I edited my code to be compilable. If you can help, that would be really appreciated. Thanks